# jQuery - Move to top of page when button clicked inside of an iFrame

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a .html with a standard form that lives within an iFrame. The form gets filled and then submitted with a submit button at the bottom of the form. The resulting action occurs at the top of the form and on some devices that means that the top of the form is not visible (off the top of browser window) when the button is clicked.

I have a .click event for the button and inside that event I have:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

This worked fine prior to placing the form within the iFrame, but it does not work from within the iFrame.

How can I accomplish the same from within an iFrame? I need to scroll to the top of the page, not just to the top of the iFrame. I tried the following code also:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("body").offset().top}, 500);
```

but it does not work either.

The HTML form is served from domain1.com, the iFrame resides in a page on domain2.com.

**DOMAIN1.COM/index.html:**

```
<html>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // EVENT Handler - Form Submission
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").bind('click', function (event) {
            ...code needed to scroll to top on DOMAIN2.COM...
        });
    });
    </script>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**DOMAIN2.COM/index.html:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://domain1.com/index.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please don't critique me on missing attributes of this code. I am not doing a copy/paste, I just typed it in quickly to give a general idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. I know there are essential attributes missing above. ;-)

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle or post some code?

Comment: jmore009, I edited my question to reflect more accurately on what I need to do. I think Khanh has me pointed in the right direction. Sorry for the incompleteness of my initial question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that your iframe and your main page are on the same domain.

Try this:

```
window.parent.scrollTo(0,0);
```

`window.parent` is the window of your main page while `window` is your current iframe's window.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/co4FoQVjrF2TmXZy0oNP?p=preview)

If your iframe and your window are on different domains, you cannot access `window.parent` directly like this. You need to use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to communicate.

If you use jQuery, you could try this [plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/).

The idea is when the button inside the iframe is clicked, the iframe will post a message to the parent page. The parent page listening to that event will be notified and scrolls itself to top. Sample code using window.postMessage in your case (not tested):

**DOMAIN1.COM/index.html:**

```
$(function () {
     $("#btnSubmit").bind('click', function (event) {
            window.postMessage("scrollTop","http://domain2.com");
     });
});
```

**DOMAIN2.COM/index.html:**

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  if (event.origin !== "http://domain1.com")
    return;

  if (event.data == "scrollTop"){
      window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Khanh, it seems like your suggestion should work - but it doesn't. It works without the iframe, but not when the form is in the iframe. You brought up a possible issue though, there are 2 domains involved. I will edit/update my question to provide more information.

Comment: @rwkiii: I added more information to deal with cross-domain scenario.

Comment: You have me worried. I do use jQuery. This application is compatible with Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE on desktops, Safari on iOS for iPhone, iPad et al, and Androids using Chrome. The plugin you referenced appears to not be compatible with all of that. I didn't consider this issue. Btw, plnkr.co is new to me and I'm not understanding how it works - or how it demonstrates my issue since there is no submit button. :S

Comment: @rwkiii: You could follow the examples in the links I posted. It should not be so difficult.

Comment: LOL, ok I will trust you on that and study them a little closer. Thank you. +1

Comment: @rwkiii: if your page and iframe are on different domains, you have to accept the fact that there are some limitations.

Comment: I do. I am aware of these sorts of issues, but to be honest I just didn't consider that navigation to the top of the page would be necessary until the closing hour. There's almost always something...

Comment: Khanh, are you able to quickly illustrate how I would script the parent and child to accomplish this based on my domain1/domain2 example above? It seems like it should be easy, but the examples include more complexity than what's needed for me.

Comment: @rwkiii: I updated the answer with sample code (not tested). Hope it helps.

Comment: This is very helpful and simplifies it like I needed. I think my biggest problem now is that my development PC enters a 3rd domain... Specifying domain1 and domain2 by hardcoding them doesn't work obviously, but I think your code makes a lot of sense to me now. I do not have access to DOMAIN2 at this time, though I do have access to DOMAIN1. Is there a way of auto-determining the URL of DOMAIN2? I'm almost 'there' and your help is appreciated.

Comment: @rwkiii: I don't know if there is no way to automatically determine the parent page domain. You could try some workarounds like passing the parent domain via a hash. Like `<iframe src="http://domain1.com/index.html#domain2.com"></iframe>` and your iframe can access it using `window.location.hash`.

Comment: Khanh, since you have experience using the jquery.ba-postmessage.js, would you know why it causes debug messages to display in the console? I use a script called Projekktor. Previously I have set its debug var to true or false to enable/display these messages. When the ba-postmessage script is included those debug messages are displayed no matter what. I've looked but don't see why. Projekktor's debug var is set to false and excluding ba-postmessage makes behavior normal.

Comment: @rwkiii: I don't know Projekktor. It could be a problem of scripts conflicting.

Comment: For anyone looking at this post as a possible solution, Khanh's code uses `window.parent.postMessage` in the code on DOMAIN1. I had to change that to `window.postMessage`. Once I did that this solution worked for me. Maybe Khanh can edit his answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. When doing it for 2 separate domains, for Domain1 example I already had a long function for the button click, I simply added `var parentWindow = window.parent;
    parentWindow.postMessage("scrollTop", "http://domain2.com");`. Without getting the parent just using window didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you must use :-

```
$(window).animate({scrollTop: $("body").offset().top}, 500);
```

instead of

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("body").offset().top}, 500);
```

Comment: I edited my question since Khanh brought up an important consideration that there are 2 domains involved.

Comment: h2O, +1 because I think you answered my question correctly, except that I left out crucial info which is my fault. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try the below

```
    window.parent.$("body").animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

Keep in mind that the iframe and the body should be able to communicate. Meaning, they both should share the same domain. Say parent is abc.xyz.com the iframe cant be abc1.xyz1.com.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have a cross domain consideration. Thank you.